# Changes being made on iframe not reflected on live site

Tags: html, iframe, localhost, page-refresh

This is pretty bizarre.  I'm running my website off local host and I'm linking to an iframe hosted locally.

```
<iframe height="780px" width="100%" src="../../shopLocator/shopLocator.php"></iframe>
```

any changes to the src and the iframe wont show up so i know I'm linking to the right place.

I can edit the file all I want, even delete it and the iframe will still show up.

It's important to note that there is a live version of this iframe available as well.  but checking the source through firebug, I see my local iframe and not the online one.

I have tried force refreshing, and clearing cache.

Comment: Delete/edit which files? What's the `src` show on the live site?

Comment: the src is showing a google maps interface.  if i delete the contents of shopLocator.php there are no changes reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You are <strike>most likely</strike> almost definitely experiencing caching problems.

- Restart the (localhost) web server
- Try a different browser
- Clear the cache in your current browser (usually CTRL+f5)

Comment: had to reference path using localhost in url